# Прочитать данные из вложенного словаря в DataFrame и отсортировать его по столбцу

Tags: python, pandas

Получаю данные с API, код:

```
okex = requests.get('https://www.okex.com/api/v1/tickers.do')
ok = pd.DataFrame(okex.json())
print (ok['tickers'])
```

вывод:

```
0      {'symbol': 'ltc_btc', 'high': '0.01983832', 'v...
1      {'symbol': 'eth_btc', 'high': '0.07642252', 'v...
2      {'symbol': 'etc_btc', 'high': '0.00219084', 'v...
```

Я уже выделил столбец 'tickers' из первоначального вывода.
Как теперь получить только 'symbol' из этого списка словарей? С конструкцией .loc у меня в данном случае не выходит.
А также, как отсортировать по алфавиту по ключу 'symbol'? .sort_values выдает ошибку 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.okex.com/api/v1/tickers.do')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['tickers']).sort_values(['symbol'])
```

Результат:

```
In [138]: df.sort_values(['symbol'])
Out[138]:
            buy        high        last         low        sell     symbol                 vol
4    0.00002185  0.00002349  0.00002348  0.00002181  0.00002293    1st_btc     988478.06142614
341  0.00029460  0.00030964  0.00030195  0.00028972  0.00030927    1st_eth     118410.63599540
169      0.1805      0.2148      0.1860      0.1730      0.1860   1st_usdt         915125.6024
5    0.00001424  0.00001504  0.00001424  0.00001400  0.00001470    aac_btc    2101321.21082546
342  0.00018755  0.00020000  0.00019220  0.00018600  0.00019220    aac_eth    3220212.26597944
170      0.1156      0.1350      0.1180      0.1071      0.1177   aac_usdt        1580062.9106
6    0.00008446  0.00009107  0.00008880  0.00008380  0.00009089    abt_btc     348259.39033788
343  0.00113579  0.00122000  0.00120000  0.00113100  0.00116321    abt_eth     195503.86468018
171      0.6805      0.8000      0.7488      0.6667      0.7488   abt_usdt         359960.2484
7    0.00001565  0.00001675  0.00001577  0.00001523  0.00001589    ace_btc    4305886.68654028
344  0.00020702  0.00021936  0.00021936  0.00019949  0.00022427    ace_eth       7783.71494710
172      0.1251      0.1544      0.1210      0.1203      0.1398   ace_usdt          58295.6212
327  0.00020064  0.00020678  0.00020042  0.00020042  0.00021540    act_bch       2000.00000000
8    0.00002338  0.00002447  0.00002335  0.00002309  0.00002396    act_btc    2379961.41871592
345  0.00031002  0.00033485  0.00031250  0.00030628  0.00031750    act_eth     341980.64783570
..          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...                 ...
159  0.00000863  0.00000920  0.00000870  0.00000831  0.00000890   yoyo_btc    7461185.47014092
490  0.00011465  0.00012280  0.00011621  0.00011466  0.00012273   yoyo_eth     205424.08218528
320      0.0704      0.0816      0.0770      0.0666      0.0770  yoyo_usdt         200689.6684
160  0.03022521  0.03216919  0.03022511  0.02961313  0.03061509    zec_btc        548.05943430
491  0.40000014  0.42037260  0.40559530  0.40000000  0.40559530    zec_eth         66.64370468
321    247.9750    280.0001    247.2991    231.6683    254.1662   zec_usdt            255.2713
161  0.00215900  0.00240651  0.00224362  0.00210001  0.00224303    zen_btc       1398.54005886
492  0.02931026  0.03615627  0.02930014  0.02852851  0.03299528    zen_eth        412.32075626
322     17.8832     21.9277     17.9998     17.0000     17.9999   zen_usdt           3259.2673
162  0.00000021  0.00000021  0.00000021  0.00000015  0.00000022    zip_btc  554212715.70879554
493  0.00000280  0.00000288  0.00000280  0.00000205  0.00000281    zip_eth  387880711.74779448
323      0.0017      0.0018      0.0017      0.0012      0.0018   zip_usdt      623690560.5031
163  0.00005943  0.00007365  0.00005986  0.00005925  0.00006133    zrx_btc      63401.27323426
494  0.00074091  0.00088648  0.00080627  0.00080627  0.00084273    zrx_eth       2944.32273648
324      0.4750      0.6034      0.4900      0.4596      0.6047   zrx_usdt          36578.1533

[495 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Благодарю, добавил дополнительный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.okex.com/api/v1/tickers.do');
text = r.text.split('"');

i = 9;
while(i < len(text)/28):
    print(text[i]);
    i += 28;
```